# Como permitir que um método execute outro método da mesma classe TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Estou trabalhando com uma classe que gerencia o cadastro e login de novos usuários. Imaginem que essa classe possui dois métodos, o primeiro `isCharacterNameRegistered()` verifica se o nick já existe, e retorna um booleano. A segunda `registerNewCharacter()` é responsável por fazer o cadastro, e antes de realizá-lo, ela também verifica se o nome (que não pode ser repetido) já foi cadastrado. Para não repetir o mesmo código, achei que seria interessante chamar a função `isCharacterRegistered()` dentro de `registerNewCharacter()` para permitir ou não o prosseguimento do cadastro. Eis a classe em questão:

```
class AuthManager {
    async isCharacterNameRegistered(characterName: string) { 
        /* verifica se o nome de personagem já é registrado, retorna true em caso afirmativo e false em caso negativo */

        const characterAlreadyRegistered = await Character.findOne({characterName})
        return !!characterAlreadyRegistered 
    }

    async registerNewCharacter(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const character = req.body

        if(this.isCharacterNameRegistered(character.characterName)) {
            return res.json({
                status: 'Erro Benigno',
                message: 'Já existe um personagem com esse nome',
                error: null
            })
        } 
    }
}
```

E temos um erro, porque o `this` dentro de `registerNewCharacter()` faz referência ao escopo da própria função em que é evocado, e não o da classe `AuthManager`, certo? tirando o `this` o TypeScript não compila, dizendo que não consegue achar `isCharacterNameRegistered` e sugere que usemos o `this`, mas como já vimos não funciona!

O que estou fazendo de errado? É possível chamar uma função diretamente dentro de outra ou preciso de um passo extra? Pensei que a abordagem sem o uso do `this` daria certo, por que chamadas de funções dentro de outras são perfeitamente possíveis em diversas linguagens, como por exemplo:

```
function dale() {
    return true
}

function dolly() {
    if(dale()) {
        console.log('dolly')
    }
}

dolly()
```

que funciona perfeitamente, mas aparentemente o contexto de uma classe traz alguma dinâmica nova, pois:

```
class Dollynho {
    dale() {
        return true
    }

    dolly() {
        if(dale()) {
            console.log('dolly')
        }
    }
}

const teste = new Dollynho

teste.dolly()
```

já não funciona

Comment: Se você não mantém estado nas instâncias da classe, é realmente necessário utilizar classe? Tenho a impressão de que você está utilizando `class` unicamente como mecanismo para separar código. Será que, nesse caso, não vale mais a pena usar um módulo?

Comment: É Felipe, acho que você tem razão. Mas apesar disso, ainda preciso lidar com classes em outros lugares e não vou conseguir dormir hoje sem tirar essa dúvida.

Comment: Como você está invocando os métodos em questão? Provavelmente o contexto (`this`) está sendo perdido, o que torna impossível referenciar métodos de instância pelo `this` pelos métodos da própria classe, como você mostrou.

Comment: @LuizFelipe seu comentário me deu uma luz danada. Antes eu exportava a classe assim: `export default new AuthManager` (é uma má prática esportar com o 'new'?) e depois importava como qualquer outro módulo dentro do meu arquivo que lida com as rotas, usando ele da seguinte forma: `routes.post('/register', AuthManager.registerNewCharacter)`

Comment: Depois do seu comentário tentei outra abordagem. exportando como: `export default AuthManager` e usando ele: `routes.post('/register', (req, res ) => {const teste = new AuthManager; teste.registerNewCharacter(req, res)})` O que funciona perfeitamente, mas não consigo me livrar da sensação de estar fazendo um trabalho porco. Acha que eu deveria apagar o post?

Comment: Não tem problema de exportar direto com o `new`. O problema que você estava tendo é por causa da perda do contexto ao passar a referência do método diretamente. O `this` em JavaScript é complicado. :) Mas a sensação de "porco" deve estar vindo do uso desnecessário de classes aí. Você está tentando usar "orientação a objetos" onde não precisa. Perceba que a sua classe não encapsula nenhum estado, então, do jeito que está, não é necessário. A "classe" que está aí só serve para separar código conforme a funcionalidade. Nesse caso, um módulo que exporta funções me parece fazer bem mais sentido.